# C#: How declare a variable to hold a sum and increment this variable each time through a while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm currently learning C# and I'm trying to find out how declare a variable to hold a sum and increment this variable each time through a while loop. My goal is to ask how many packages the user wants to ship, then get the weight for each package (using a while loop). The issue is how to take the input for each input (however many packages the user has dictated to send) and assign it to a variable without overriding the last entry in the while loop while adding them all together and displaying the combined about as "total".

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Package Shipping Calculator");

        //ask user how many packages they want to ship
        Console.Write("How many packages would you like to ship? ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        string userinput2;
        double result;
        double total=0;

        //create loop for weight in lbs that the package weighs. Multiply $2.35 per pound (weight*2.35)
        //for each increment, then add the result
        int counter = 1;

        while (counter <= int.Parse(userinput))
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the weight of package {0}: ", counter);
            userinput2 = Console.ReadLine();
            result = double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;

            counter++;
        }

        counter --;

        Console.Write("\nThe cost to ship {0} packages is {1:C}", counter, total);



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

As you can see, I have the counter going to ask how many times it needs to ask for the weight, but I don't know how to take the amount for each package and add them together inside of the loop. I would greatly appreciate help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already broken the problem down in the statement of the question: declare the variable, increment it in a loop. So solve each problem. Do you know how to declare a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Took me a sec to figure out the problem because it was so small! you need to change `result = double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;` to `result += double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;`

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, you're really close. The only thing I could suggest is that you add the previous amount of `result` to itself each time it's goes through it's loop. Such as

```
while (counter <= int.Parse(userinput))
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter the weight of package {0}: ", counter);
        userinput2 = Console.ReadLine();
        result = (double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35) + result;

        counter++;
    }
```

You should not have a problem with this as you've already declared `result` above as `0`

Answer (score 1):

In you code add

```
total = total + result;
```

right after

```
result = double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;
```

Comment: Your suggestion and B. Witter's suggestion both worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the great recommendations combined, I was able to find the answer to my question. I changed `result = double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;` to `result += double.Parse(userinput2) * 2.35;` and then declared my variable `result=0` as before it was not assigned a value. I removed `total` from my final Write line as the method I changed to no longer needed it.

Comment: If my Answer or Armin's Answer were the one you went with, feel free to mark the one you went with as the Accepted Answer, so that the question can be resolved. Glad its working for ya!

Cheers!